# Merge two identical tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in sql server 2008 R2.
one table has records as follows, this table is called ASTM_Table

[image: ASTM_Tables]

and another table called ASTM1 is like this

[image]

Astm1 table contains gravity with 0.1 difference while "astm_table" has gravity with a difference of 0.5 (However, this table is the latest)

All i want is to have all those records from astm1 table and merge them in astm_table, but only those records that are not available in astm_table.

For example, in astm_table, gravity 54.1, 54.2, 54.3, 54.4, 54.6, 54.7, 54.8, 54.9 are not available. so i want to get these values from astm1 table and copy them in astm_table.

is it possible and yes then which query would do the job right? Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I"m understanding you correctly, you just want to insert all the rows from ASTM1, except those already in ASTM_Table. In that case:

```
INSERT INTO ASTM_Table
(astm_id,Table_No,Temperature,Gravity,Result)
SELECT
id,
TBLE,
TEMPR,
GRV_OB,
GRV_SP
FROM ASTM1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ASTM_Table X WHERE X.Gravity=GRV_OB)
```

Comment: let me try... its looks somewhat resolving... wait

Comment: can you do it only for table_no '5a' please???? and i want to just add 10 records initially just to check. I can not run this query with over 2 millions records without testing.. Please can u help

Comment: i somehow managed to change the above query, and resolved the issue, thanks jackson

Answer (score 1):

I just smiplified your query in an example please try this ..

```
create table dbo.t1(id int identity(1,1) not null,col1 int,col2 int)
go
create table dbo.t2(id int identity(1,1) not null,col1 int,col2 int)
go
insert into dbo.t1 values(102,22),(32,33),(10,11)
insert into dbo.t2 values(102,22),(32,33),(10,11),(33,55),(44,66)
go
select id,col1,col2 from t2 
except 
select id,col1,col2 from t1
go
drop table t1,t2
```

Comment: I've resolved the problem, but thanks for the efforts bro. Upvote!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO ASTM_Tables
(Table_No,Temperature,Gravity,Result)
SELECT TBLE, TEMPR, GRV_OB, GRV_SP
FROM ASTM1
WHERE
tble = '5a' and
not EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ASTM_Tables X WHERE X.Gravity = GRV_OB and x.table_no = tble)
order by tble, tempr, grv_ob
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

[EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

You might want to look specifically at the `EXCEPT` stament